# A question on the Lemma 41.3. of Munkres' Topology

Tags: general-topology

Inside the Lemma 41.3. of Munkres' Topology, it is written (without proof) that ($X$ is regular) :

> Let $A$ be an open covering of $X$. Let $B$ be the collection of all open sets $U$ **of** $X$ such that $Cl(U)$ is contained in an element of $A$. By regularity, $B$ covers $X$.

I can't prove the last statement : "By regularity, $B$ covers $X$". Simple clear explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: The usual def'n of regularity of $X$ is that if $x\in X$ and $x\not \in C=\bar C\subset X$ then there are disjoint open subsets $U,V$ of $X$ such that $x\in U$ and $C\subset V$. An (easily proven) equivalent and often useful def'n is that if $x\in S\subset X$ where $S$ is open then there is an open $T\subset X$  such that $x\in T\subset \bar T\subset S.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in X$. Let $S\in A$ such that $x\in S$. $X\backslash S$ is closed and $x\notin X\backslash S$, and so by regularity, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and an open neighborhood $V$ of $X\backslash S$ such that $U\cap V = \varnothing$. Now, $X\backslash V$ is a closed set containing $U$, and so $\mathrm{cl}(U) \subseteq X\backslash V \subseteq S$. Therefore, $x\in U\in B$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $B$ covers $X$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a direct consequence of Lemma 31.1 (a). I rewrite the crucial part: If $X$ is regular, then, for any point $x$, and any open set $A$ containing $x$, there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $\bar{U}\subset A$.

Now, since $\mathcal{A}$ is an open covering of $X$, for every $x \in X$ there must be an $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $x\in A$. Then, for any $x \in X$, we can find an open set $U$ satisfying the defining conditions of the collection $\mathcal{B}$.